# AS3 TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, static, typeerror

For some reason I can't get this to work (heavily simplified code that fails):

```
package com.domain {
    public class SomeClass {
        private static var helper:Helper = new Helper();
    }
}

class Helper {
}
```

It compiles, but throws upon first access of `SomeClass`:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
    at com.domain::SomeClass$cinit()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to Darren.  Another option is to move the `Helper` class to the top of the file

```
class Helper {
}

package com.domain {
    public class SomeClass {
        private static var helper:Helper = new Helper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Had no idea you could do this. Haven't had a chance to test, but if it works this is it.

Comment: This is pretty cool, I too had no idea you could do this.
That said, for my specific use case, I still don't think it would work (I am yet to test it tbh)... the Flex compiler really ought to parse the entire file, before compiling anything

Answer (score 2):

The *non-constructor* error is the compiler's awkward way of saying 'you have called a constructor for a class I have not seen yet'; if it were a bit smarter, it could check the file (compilation unit) for internal classes before complaining... mehhh

Seeing as you have given your static variable `private` access, obviously you intend to only use the instance internally to `SomeClass` (*assumption; could be passed out as a return value*).

The following solution defers creation of the static var to when the internal class is initialized i.e. when the (presumably implicit) `Helper.cinit()` is invoked, rather than `SomeClass.cinit()` when `Helper` *does not exist yet*:

```
package com.domain {
    public class SomeClass {

        public function doSomething(param:*):void {
            // ... use Helper.INSTANCE
        }

    }
}

class Helper {
    public static const INSTANCE:Helper = new Helper();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can't work with Helper and SomeClass both in the same file.
When SomeClass is initialized, the Helper class has not been initialized yet, and so a Helper object can't be created.

Moving Helper to a separate file should solve the problem.

Comment: He wrote that this example is "heavily simplified code that fails". I think he has it in two separated files.

Comment: Actually, they are meant to be in the same file. @silyevsk, I think that this indeed is an initialization order issue.

Comment: It **has** to be in the same file, this is how you create a [private constructor in Actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17464207/238419)

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate a constructor and declare your variable in the class, not the function:

```
package com.domain { 
    public class SomeClass { 
        private static var helper:Helper 
        public function SomeClass() {
           helper = new Helper(); 
        }
    } 
} 

class Helper { 
}
```

Comment: Interesting... This seems to work, although this approach means that you have to instantiate `SomeClass` before the static member `helper` is available. Also, kinda weird to initialize a static member in an instance constructor. E.g., if you create multiple instances of `SomeClass`, the static member will be reset each time... Not what you want. Another example, if you have a static method using `helper`, it will find it to be `null` _until_ you instantiate `SomeClass` at least once. Weird, to say the least.

Comment: you mustn't instantiate inside the constuctor. So you don't overwrite it each time you instance SomeClass.

Comment: But when you instantiate new Helper() you call the constructor of class Helper and this is where the error occurs. Helper has no constructor?

Comment: @Wolv3r: as written, your example will cause a new Helper to be created on every new instance of SomeClass, which is surely not desired with a static variable.

Comment: Agree with @Blanka, this is very weird and a bonafide anti-pattern, however the reason why the compiler likes it is because it has had a chance to initialize `Helper` before its constructor is called.
@Wolv3r, AS3 supports implicit definition and invocation of no-arg constructors