# Error 1007- Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

New error for me- can't see why this is problem -
It compiles then fails with Error 1007
Despite changing considerable amounts of code- its still the same error 
Clearing the debugger window allows it to run everything but tile.as.

As per Pulsar's request here is the entire code for the two problem files.

This is in Main.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    //import board;
    import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityImplementation;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
    import flash.utils.describeType;
    import boxsprite;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import board;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.KeyboardType;
    import Set;
    import tile;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Michael
     */

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

    [Embed(source="../lib/Board.jpg")]
        private var boardClass :Class;

        public function Main():void
        {if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }
        private var t1:Sprite;
        private var t2:Sprite;
        private var t3:Sprite;
        private var t4:Sprite;
        private var t5:Sprite;
            private var t6:Sprite;
        private var t7:Sprite;
        private var base:Sprite;
        private var tilex:Sprite;
        private var boardonScreen:Bitmap;
        private var box1:Sprite;
        private function init():void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
                    boardonScreen= new boardClass() as Bitmap;
            boardonScreen.x = 0;
                  boardonScreen.y = 0;
                 stage.addChild(boardonScreen);
            box1 = new boxsprite();
            box1.x = 480;
            box1.y = 0;
            stage.addChild(box1);
            base = new tile();
                base.x =672;
            base.y = 448;
            stage.addChild(base);
            t1 = new tile();
            t1.x = 480;
            t1.y = 448;
            stage.addChild(t1);
            t2 = new tile();
            t2.x = 480;
            t2.y = 416;
            stage.addChild(t2);
                    t3 = new tile();
            t3.x = 480;
            t3.y = 384;
            stage.addChild(t3);
            t4 = new tile();
            t4.x = 480;
            t4.y = 352;
            stage.addChild(t4);
            t5 = new tile();
            t5.x = 480;
            t5.y = 320;
            stage.addChild(t5);
            t6 = new tile();
            t6.x = 480;
            t6.y = 288;
            stage.addChild(t6);
            t7 = new tile();
            t7.x = 480;
            t7.y = 256;
           stage.addChild(t7);}}}
```

In the file: tiles.as

```
package {
    import fl.transitions.*;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import lob;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import Math;
    import Main;
    import boxsprite;
    import StatusBox;
    import Set;
    ///These import functions are used to ease the button back into place after a drag
    public class tile extends Sprite
    {   private var kana:String;
        private var value:uint;
        //private const backingcolour:uint = 0xe0e0e0;
        private var type:uint;
        private var isSetBox:Boolean;
        private static var valueaggreg:uint; //value of kanjitile
        static private var ret:Boolean; //do you return tiles from board
        static private var yplace:uint = 0;


        private var xx:int;
        private var yy:uint;
        private var initialx:uint;
        private var initialy:uint;
        private var finalx:uint;
        private var finaly:uint;
            private var id:uint;
        private var selectghostList:Vector.<String>=new<String>["ま,マ","む,ム","も,モ","か,カ","く,ク","こ,コ","な,ナ","ぬ,ヌ","の,ノ","ば,バ","ぶ,ブ","ぼ,ボ","は,ハ","ふ,フ","ほ,ホ","ぱ,パ","ぷ,プ","ぽ,ポ"];
        private var selectkanaList:Vector.<String>=new <String>["みゃ,ミャ", "みゅ,ミャ", "みょ,ミョ", "きゃ,キャ", "きゅ,キュ", "きょ,キョ", "にゃ,ニャ", "にゅ,ニュ", "にょ,ニョ", "びゃ,びゃ", "びゅ,ビュ", "びょ,ビョ", "　　ひゃ,ヒャ", "ひゅ,ヒュ", "ひょ,ヒョ", "ぴゃ,ピャ", "ぴゅ,ピュ", "ぴょ,ピョ"];
        private var selectghostvalueList:Vector.<uint> = new <uint>[2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
    private const multiplier:Array = [["TW","1","1","DL","1","1","1","TW","1","1","1","DL","1","1","TW"],["1","DW","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","DW","1"],["1","1","DW","1","1","1","DL","1","DL","1","1","1","DW","1","1"],["DL","1","1","DW","1","1","1","DL","1","1","1","DW","1","1","DL"],["1","1","1","1","DW","1","1","1","1","1","DW","1","1","1","1"],["1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1"],["1","1","DL","1","1","1","DL","1","DL","1","1","1","DL","1","1"],["TW","1","1","DL","1","1","1","DL","1","1","1","DL","1","1","TW"],["1","1","DL","1","1","1","DL","1","DL","1","1","1","DL","1","1"],["1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1"],["1","1","1","1","DW","1","1","1","1","1","DW","1","1","1","1"],["DL","1","1","DW","1","1","1","DL","1","1","1","DW","1","1","DL"],["1","1","DW","1","1","1","DL","1","DL","1","1","1","DW","1","1"],["1","DW","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","TL","1","1","1","DW","1"],["TW","1","1","DL","1","1","1","TW","1","1","1","DL","1","1","TW"]];
    private var vis:Boolean = true; //visibility
private var isSet:Boolean;
    [Embed(source = "C:/Users/Makiko/Desktop/Michael/Games/Test/New Project/lib/Tile.png")]
    private var tileClass:Class
    private var kanaList:Vector.<String> = new <String>["あ,ア", "あ,ア", "え,エ", "え,エ", "い,イ", "い,イ", "お,オ", "お,オ", "う,ウ", "う,ウ", "う,ウ", "う,ウ", "か,カ", "か,カ", "け,ケ", "け,ケ", "き,キ", "き,キ", "く,ク", "く,ク", "こ,コ", "こ,コ", "さ,サ", "さ,サ", "　し,シ", "　し,シ", "す,ス", "す,ス", "そ,ソ", "そ,ソ", "す,ス", "す,ス", "た,タ", "た,タ", "て,テ", "て,テ", "　ち,チ", "　ち,チ", "と,ト", "と,ト", "つ,ツ", "つ,ツ", "ら,ラ", "ら,ラ", "れ,レ", "れ,レ", "り,リ", "り,リ", "ろ,ロ", "ろ,ロ", "る,ル", "る,ル", "だ,ダ", "で,デ", "じ,ジ", "ど／ド", "ず,ズ", "ざ,ザ", "ぜ,ゼ", "ぞ／ゾ", "な,ナ", "ね,ネ", "に,二", "の,ノ", "ぬ,ヌ", "じゃ,ジャ", "じゅ,ジュ", "じょ,ジョ", "ん,ン", "しゃ,シャ", "しゅ,シュ", "しょ,ショ", "や,ヤ", "ゆ,ユ", "よ,ヨ", "は,ハ", "ひ,ヒ", "ふ,フ", "へ,ヘ", "ほ,ホ", "ば,バ", "ば,バ", "ぶ,ブ", "ぶ,ブ", "び,ビ", "び,ビ", "ぼ,ボ", "ぼ,ボ", "べ,ベ", "べ,ベ", "ぱ,パ", "ぴ／ピ", "ぷ,プ", "ぺ,ペ", "ぽ,ポ", "ま,マ", "み,ミ", "　む,ム", "め,メ", "も,モ", "を／ヲ", "みゃ,ミャ", "みゅ,ミャ", "みょ,ミョ", "きゃ,キャ", "きゅ,キュ", "きょ,キョ", "にゃ,ニャ", "にゅ,ニュ", "にょ,ニョ", "びゃ,びゃ", "びゅ,ビュ", "びょ,ビョ", "ひゃ,ヒャ", "ひゅ,ヒュ", "ひょ,ヒョ", "ぴゃ,ピャ", "ぴゅ,ピュ", "ぴょ,ピョ", "っ,ッ", "っ,ッ"];
    private var valueList:Vector.<uint>= new <uint>[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1];
    // Lists of Kana that can be replaced in the replace mode and the substitute Kana and Values
    //Start list of playerHand contents as I don't know if Null is 0
     private var playernumber:uint; //total number of players
     private var allplayersHand:Array = [[], [], [], [],[], []];
    private var playerRound:uint = 1; //which player
    private var round:uint = 1; //round of the game
    private var aplayersHand:Array; // hand of the current player
    private var mode:uint;
    private var tileImage:Bitmap;
    private static var idvar:uint;
    static private var first:Boolean = true;
    private var special:Boolean = false;
    static private var handstatus:Vector.<String>;
    //handstatus types are idle: free, ret: ready to return to stock, set: set on        board, rem: ready to removed, not
    public function tile()
    { addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, standarddisplay) }
                private function standarddisplay(e:Event=void) : void
           {trace("Project is running fine!");
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, standarddisplay);
            tileImage = new tileClass as Bitmap;
            addChild(tileImage);
            //Draws the japanese letter on the tile
              var kanafield:TextField = new TextField();
              kanafield.width = 40;
              kanafield.height = 20;
              kanafield.x = -2;
              kanafield.y = -5;
              kanafield.text == "";
              trace(kanafield.text);
              kanafield.wordWrap = true;
              kanafield.background = true;
              var kanafieldformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
              kanafieldformat.size = 12;
              kanafieldformat.font = "Arial";
              kanafield.setTextFormat(kanafieldformat);
              this.addChild(kanafield);
              kanafield.mouseEnabled = false;
             //Draw the number on the tile
              valuefield= new TextField();
              valuefield.width = 30;
              valuefield.height = 10;
              valuefield.x = 0;
              var valuefieldformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
              valuefieldformat.size = 7;
              valuefield.text = "";
              valuefield.y = 15;
              valuefield.background = false;
              valuefield.setTextFormat(valuefieldformat);
              this.addChild(valuefield);
              valuefield.mouseEnabled = false;
            //Add an event listener to the tile on the stage
            checktype(); }
            private function checktype():void
            {if (first != true)
                   {   id = idvar;
                        idvar += 1;
                    value = playerhandvalue[id];
                        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyboardinput);
                        this.addEventListener(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED,moderesponse);
                        this.addEventListener(StatusBox.HIDE, SetAlpha);
                        isSetBox = false }
                    else
                        {   special = true;
                      first = false;
                     this.addEventListener(Set.BOX_SET_CHANGED,btr)
                    init();}}
                   private function init():void
                           { trace("starting");
                           stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
                           stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dnp);}
                   private function dnp(e:MouseEvent):void
                {   stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,myKeyDown);
                        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dnp);
                    trace(playernumber);
                    create();   }
    private function myKeyDown(e2:KeyboardEvent):void
            { if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1)
                {playernumber = 1;
                 trace(playernumber);}
                     else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_2)
                   {playernumber = 2;
                            trace(playernumber) 
                     else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_3)
                              {playernumber = 3;
                               trace(playernumber);}                                                      
                    else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_4)
                {playernumber = 4;
                             trace(playernumber); }
                    else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_5)
                             {playernumber = 5;
                              trace(playernumber);}
             else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_6)
                {playernumber = 6; }
             else {playernumber = 1;}}
            private function create():void
            { var listLength:uint;
              var row:uint
                    aplayersHand = allplayersHand[playerRound];
                   for (var i:uint = (aplayersHand.length-1); i <= 6; i+=1)
             {  listLength = kanaList.length;
            row = int(Math.random() * listLength);                    　
                trace (row);
               trace(i);
              aplayersHand[i] = [0, kanaList[row], valueList[row],]
                   trace (aplayersHand);
              trace (aplayersHand[i]);

                  kanaList.splice(row,1);


                  valueList.splice(row, 1);

                  playerhandkana.push(kanaList[row]);

                  playerhandvalue.push(valueList[row]);}
                  dispatchEvent( new StatusBox(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED, 1));                          
                  }
                  private function moderesponse(e:StatusBox):void
            { mode = e.mode;
                          cleanup();
                if (special == false)
                        {
                        if (mode == 1)
                          { this.visible = true;
                           this.kanafield.visible = true;
                        this.valuefield.visible = true;
                       this.x = 480;
                         this.y = (480 - (id*32));
                      kana =  playerhandkana[id];
                      value = playerhandvalue[id];
                       kanafield.text = kana;
                       valuefield.text = String(value);
                       this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, draglocation);
               }
        else if (mode == 4)
        {if (handstatus[id] == "rem")
            {handstatus[id] = "idle"; } }   }
        else if (special == true)
        { if (mode == 8)
        {stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboardinput);
        for (var i:uint = 0; (handstatus.length - 1); i += 1)
        {if (handstatus[i] == "ret")
             {kanaList.push(playerhandkana[i]);
             valueList.push(playerhandvalue[i]);
             endgame = true;}       }
        if (endgame == true)
        {       dispatchEvent(new StatusBox(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED, 9, false, false));}
        else        {{var cfh:Boolean = checkforwordtype(horzword);
            var cfv:Boolean = (checkforwordtype(vertword));
            var hl2:uint;
            if ((handstatus.length > 1 && (cfh == false) && (cfv == false)))
            {dispatchEvent(new StatusBox(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED, 10, false, false));}
            if (generalx.length == 0)
            {for (var j:uint = 0; (handstatus.length - 1); i += 1)
              {if (handstatus[i] == "set")
                 {hl2 += 1 } }
              if (hl2 == 1)
              {dispatchEvent(new StatusBox(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED, 10, false, false)); }}
            if ((cfh == true) && (cfv == true))
             {dispatchEvent(new StatusBox(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED, 10, false, false));   }
            else if (cfh == true)
            {calctotalscore(valuehor, valuevert);}
             else if (cfv == true)
             {calctotalscore(valuevert, valuehor);  }   }   }
            for (var k:uint = 0; k < (handstatus.length - 1); k += 1)
            { if(handstatus[i] == "idle" || "rem")
             {  var o:uint=0
                 allplayersHand[playernumber][o] = [kana, value];
                 o += 1; }}}
        else if (mode == 9)
         {if (ret == true)
         { ret = false;
          for (var m:uint = 0; m < (handstatus.length - 1); m += 1)
            { if(handstatus[i] == "set")
             {  var p:uint=0
                 allplayersHand[playernumber][p] = [kana, value];
                 p += 1; }}
         dispatchEvent(new StatusBox(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED, 1, false, false));}
         else { setinplace();
                dispatchEvent(new StatusBox(StatusBox.STATUSBOXCHANGED, 1, true, true));
         }  }
         else if (mode == 10)
         {isSet = false;
    isSetBox = false;
    this.visible = false;
    create();}}}
    private function btr(e:Set):void
        {if (e.valueex > 0)
        {   if (e.kanaex == "kanji")
         {kanafield.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
          value += e.valueex;
          valuefield.text = String(value);}
         else if (e.kanaex == "k+" )
         {value += e.valueex;
         valuefield.text = String(value);}
         else if (e.kanaex == "k-")
         {value-= e.valueex;
         valuefield.text = String(value);}
         else if (e.kanaex == "nokanji")
         {kanafield.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
          value = 0;
          kana = "";
          valuefield.text = "";}}
         else
         {if (kana == "")
          { if (e.valueex == 0)
            {kana =selectghostList[selectkanaList.indexOf(e.kanaex, 0)];
             value = selectghostvalueList[selectkanaList.indexOf(kana, 0)];
             kanafield.text = kana;
            valuefield.text = String(value);}
            else
            {kana = "";
            value = 0;
            kanafield.text = "";
            valuefield.text = "";}}}}
    private var error:String;
    private function SetAlpha(e:StatusBox):void
    { if (isSetBox == true)
        {this.alpha = 0;
        this.mouseEnabled = false;  }   }
        static private var scorelist:Array = [[]];
    private function setinplace():void {
        if (isSet==true)    {
            /*var lob1:Sprite = new lob(kana, value);
                lob1.x = xx;
                lob1.y = yy;
                stage.addChild(lob1);*/
                removeEventListener(StatusBox.SETDOWN, setinplace);
                stage.removeChild(this);}
                else        {stage.removeChild(this);}  }
    static private var turnscore:uint;
    static private function calctotalscore(main:Vector.<uint>,side:Vector.<uint>):uint
    {  var  tws:uint;
       var twm:uint;
       var amws:uint;
       var asws:uint;
        for (var i:uint = 0; (handstatus.length - 1); i += 1)
              {if (handstatus[i] == "set")
                 { if (side[i] > 0)
                     {asws += (side[i] + (exclusionvalue[i] * LM[i])) * WM[i]; }
                    amws += main[i] + (exclusionvalue[i] * LM[i])
                    twm += WM[i]
                    generalx.push(exclusionx[i]);
                    generaly.push(exclusiony[i]);
                 generalkana.push(exclusionkana[i]);
                    generalvalue.push(exclusionvalue[i]);}}
              exclusionx = new  Vector.<uint>
              exclusiony = new Vector.<uint>
              exclusionkana = new Vector.<String>
              exclusionvalue= new Vector.<uint>
              tws = (asws + amws) * twm;
             return tws;}
    private function checkforwordtype(wordcheck:Vector.<Boolean>):Boolean
    {   for (var i:uint = 0; handstatus.length - 1; i += 1)
    {  var check:Boolean = false;
        if (handstatus[i] == "set")
        {if (wordcheck[i] == true)
        {check = true;}}}
        return check;}
    private var endgame:Boolean;
    private var playerhandkana:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(7);
    private var playerhandvalue:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>(7);
    private var valuefield:TextField;
    private function keyboardinput(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {   if (mode == 2 || 3 || 4 || 5||8)
        {if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.I)
        { vis = !vis;
        if ((isSet=false)&&(isSetBox=false))
        {this.visible = vis;
         this.kanafield.visible = vis;
        this.valuefield.visible = vis;}}}
        if (mode == 8)
        {if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.R)
        {ret = !ret; }}}
    private var kanafield:TextField = new TextField();
           static  private var generalx:Vector.<uint>;
           static private var generaly:Vector.<uint>;
           static private var generalkana:Vector.<String>;
           static private var generalvalue:Vector.<uint>;
           static private var exclusionx:Vector.<uint>;
            static private var exclusiony:Vector.<uint>;
            static private var exclusionvalue:Vector.<uint>;
            static private var exclusionkana:Vector.<String>;
            private function addExclusion():void
            {exclusionx[id]=xx;
                exclusiony[id] = yy;
                exclusionkana[id] = kana;
                exclusionvalue[id] = value; }
                private function removeExclusion():void
                { exclusionvalue[id] = 0;
                  exclusionkana[id] = "0";
                  exclusionx[id] = 0;
                  exclusiony[id] = 0;   }
//The initial event performed when the button is first clicked;
            private function draglocation(e:MouseEvent):void
            {   removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, draglocation);
                initialx = this.x;
                initialy = this.y;
                if (isSet==false ||isSetBox == false)
                {   stage.addChild(this)
                this.startDrag();
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clickcheck);}        }
            private function clickcheck(e:Event):void
            {  if (isSetBox==false || isSet == false)
                { this.stopDrag();
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clickcheck);}
                finalx = this.x;
                finaly = this.y;
                if ((((finaly - initialy) ^ 2 + (finalx - initialx) ^ 2)^0.5) < 5)
                {HandleDoubleClick();   }   }
             private function HandleDoubleClick():void
        {if (this.x < 480 && this.y < 480)
                {if (isSet == false)
                      {isSet = true;
                  this.stopDrag();
                   xx= int((this.x+16) / 32);
                      this.x = 32*xx;
                     yy= int((this.y+16) / 32);
                     this.y = (32 * yy);
                     for (var i:uint = 0; i < (exclusionx.length-1); i += 1)
                     {if (xx == exclusionx[i] && yy == exclusiony[i])
                     {notSet = true }}
                     if (generalx.length > 0)
                     {var notSet:Boolean;
                     　　　for (var q:uint = 0; q < (generalx.length - 1); q += 1)
                      {if (xx == generalx[q] && yy == generaly[q])
                     {notSet = true }
                     else {notSet=false}}}
                  if (notSet == false)
                     {handstatus[id] = "set";
                     addExclusion();
                     notSet = true; }
                      else {isSet = false;}}
                else { handstatus[id] = "idle";
                  removeExclusion();}}
            else if (this.x > 480 && this.y < 480 && this.x < 704)
                {if (isSetBox == false)
                         {setonbox(); }
                             else {takeoffbox(); }} }
                             static private var killsetBox: Boolean;
            static private var WM:Vector.<uint>;
            static private var LM:Vector.<uint>;
            static private var horzword:Vector.<Boolean>;
            static private var vertword:Vector.<Boolean>;
            static private var idtoreplace:uint;
            private function rawscore(calcx:int, calcy:int):uint
            { var xincr:uint = 1;
            var yincr:uint = 1;
            var value:uint = 0;
            while ((Number(boardarray[xx + (calcx * xincr)][yy + calcy * yincr])) != 0)
                { value += (boardarray[xx + (calcx * xincr)][yy + calcy * yincr]);
                  xincr += 1; yincr += 1;   }
                    if (value == 0)
                    { for (var i:uint = 0; exclusionx.length - 1;i+=1)
                        { if (((exclusionx[i] == exclusionx[id]+calcx) && (exclusiony[i] == exclusiony[id] + calcy)))
                         {if (Math.abs(calcx) == 1)
                         { horzword[id] = true;}
                            else    {vertword[id] = true; } }   }   }
            return value;   }
            static private var valuehor:Vector.<uint>;
            static private var valuevert:Vector.<uint>;
    static private var boardarray:Array=new Array[[]];
            private function checkscore():void
            { switch(multiplier[exclusionx[id], exclusiony[id]])
                {case "TW": WM[id] = 3; LM[id] = 1; break;
                 case "DW": WM[id] = 2; LM[id] = 1; break;
                 case "TL": LM[id] = 3; WM[id] = 1; break;
                 case "DL": LM[id] = 2; WM[id] = 1; break;
                 default: LM[id] = 1; WM[id] = 1;}
                     valuehor[id] = rawscore(1, 0) + rawscore( -1, 0);
                     valuevert[id] = rawscore(0, 1) + rawscore(0, -1);  }
            private function cleanup():void
                    { if (mode == 2 || 3 || 4 || 5)
                      {   yplace = 0;
                          if (killsetBox=false)
                           {isSetBox = false;
                          handstatus[id] = "idle"; }
                          else
                          {if (isSetBox ==true)
                                 { this.visible = false;
                                   this.kanafield.visible = false;
                                   this.valuefield.visible = false;
                                 handstatus[id] = "not";
                    killsetBox = false; }    }  }}
    private var first:Boolean = true;
    private function kanachange(e:Set):void
    {   if (id==handstatus.indexOf(e.kanaex,0))
        {kana = e.kanaex;
        value = e.valueex;
        kanafield.text = kana;
        valuefield.text = String(value);
        playerhandkana[id] = e.kanaex;
        playerhandvalue[id] = e.valueex;}
        else
        { kana = "";
        value = 0;
    handstatus[id] = "not";}}
    private function setonbox():void
            {addEventListener(Set.BOARD_SET_CHANGED, kanachange);
             if (mode==3)
             {isSetBox = true;
             this.x = 480;
             this.y = 448 - (yplace * 32);
             handstatus[id] = "ret";}
             else if (mode == 4)
             {   if (yplace == 0)
             {dispatchEvent(new Set(Set.BOX_SET_CHANGED, kana, 0));
             isSetBox = true;
             this.x = 480;
             this.y = 448 - (yplace * 32);
             handstatus[id] = "rem";} }
             else if (mode == 5)
             { { isSetBox = true;
             this.x = 480;
             this.y = 448 - (yplace * 32);}
             if (yplace == 0)
              {dispatchEvent(new Set(Set.BOX_SET_CHANGED, "kanji", value)); }
             else if (yplace > 0)
             {dispatchEvent(new Set(Set.BOX_SET_CHANGED, "k+", value));  }
            yplace += 1; }}
             private function takeoffbox():void
             { removeEventListener(Set.BOARD_SET_CHANGED, kanachange);
               isSetBox = false;
             if (mode == 3)
             { handstatus[id] = "idle";
             isSetBox=false}
             else if (mode ==4)
             { if (yplace == 1)
             {dispatchEvent(new Set(Set.BOX_SET_CHANGED, kana, 1));
             isSetBox = false;
             handstatus[id] = "idle"  }
             else if (mode == 5)
             { if (yplace == 1)
             {dispatchEvent(new Set(Set.BOX_SET_CHANGED, "nokanji", value));         }
             else if (yplace > 1)
             {dispatchEvent(new Set(Set.BOX_SET_CHANGED, "k-", value));  }}
              handstatus[id] = "idle";
                yplace-= 1;          }}
            private function goodX(inX:Number):Number
            {if (inX < 0)
            {return 0;}
            if (inX > (stage.stageWidth) )
            {return (stage.stageWidth);
            }return inX;}
            private function goodY(inY:Number):Number {
            if (inY < 0)
            {return 0;  }
            if (inY > stage.stageHeight) {return stage.stageHeight;}
            return inY; }
                private function turn1():void
                             {if (playerRound > playernumber)
                                 {playerRound = 1;
                                 round += 1;
                                 } }    }}
```

Comment: seems to me your `tiles.as` must be `tile.as` , as a class name , isn't it?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010041/as3-typeerror-error-1007-instantiation-attempted-on-a-non-constructor

Comment: I saw that first- it doesn't seem completely solved nor completely relevant.

Comment: You need to format your code some more.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor shouldn't have a return type.

Try:

```
public function tile(i:uint,kana1:String,value1:uint, type1:uint)
{ 
    id = i;
    kana = kana1;
    value = value1;
    type = type1;
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, go); // this function will be called when you create a new tile object
}
```

Also, another potential problem in the future is your init method doesn't have any parameters so it will throw an error if your `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` triggers the init method.

Try:

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't make any difference. removing reference to tile and it suddenly it "works"- it just seems to dislike that tile takes arguments- I suppose I could try to do it without arguments, tile is also a self-constructor with one sprite set to do construction. The other sprite had no problem with constructor set to return void and no argument for its added to stage listener function, "private function go"  really is the first private function in tile not init.

Comment: I can't see any other syntax errors there so post your full code for the tile class and whatever file the function `Main()` is in.

Comment: tile class is 500 lines long and not commented.

Comment: Well all I can say is that this error normally occurs when something other than a class name is placed after the `new` keyword. So check for another function definition called tile anywhere in that scope.

Comment: Didn't have any of that- but I am changing it anyway to remove any need for garbage collection during the normal course of the game so no instantiation in the class and no arguments to form the sprite- hopefully that should help.

Comment: By the way, you need to remove the return type from Main's constructor as well.